# Remove text from before content CSS

Tags: css, html

I have a tag link with the text "Suggestions" but in mobile devices I have a CSS rule to change it to an icon as follows:

```
a:before {
    font-family: "Linearicons";
    content: "\e697";
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

The problem is that in mobile devices also appears the text "Suggestions" and I want only the icon. Any idea of how to solve it?

Comment: why don't you wrap the content of the `<a>` in a `<span>` and with a media query for mobile devices hide it . Example `<a href='...' class='my-link'> <i>my_nice_icon_here</i><span>Suggestions</span></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another to make sure text is hidden,

```
a {font-size: 0px;}    

a:before {
font-family: "Linearicons";
content: "\e697";
display: inline-block;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 22px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

For your **mobile styles** set `visibility: hidden;`on the `a` element to hide the text, then set `visibility: visible;` on generated content to show the icon.

```
a {
    visibility: hidden; /* hide the text */
    max-width: 0;
  }
a:before {
  ... /* some styling */
  visibility: visible; /* show the icon */
}
```

Note that the `visibility` property is different than the `display` property in that it allows a parent element to be hidden and a child to be visible.

From the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box-3/#visibility-prop): (bold mine)

> **hidden**
>
> The generated box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is
>   drawn), but still affects layout. Furthermore, **descendants of the
>   element will be visible** if they have '`visibility: visible`'.

**Demo Snippet:**

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) { 
  a {
    visibility: hidden;
    max-width: 0;
  }
  a:before {
    font-family: "Linearicons";
    content: "\e697";
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Suggestions</a>
```

### [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/GOBvwb) (Resize to see effect)

Comment: Note that you will have to set the width of the `a` if the content of `a:before` is much shorter than the one of `a`. Otherwise, there will be a gap to the following text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use visibility property in media query to solve it

```css
a{
  position:relative;
  padding:4px 0px 0px 20px;
}
a:before {
        font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    content: "\f129";
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  a{
  visibility: hidden;
}
a:before {
    visibility: visible;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<a>Suggestions</a>
```